# WP7 tombstoning Memory Save

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

So for my windows phone 7 app, I am trying to save the user input after they 'tombstone' my app when I first debugged the app I got a KeyNotFoundException, but after I entered some data into my textbox and tombstoned my app the I didn't get a KeyNotFoundException. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: You should post some of the code you're using for tombstoning...

Answer (score 0):

KeyNotFoundException means that you are trying to get some data from data collection by key, and that key/value pair does not exist:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception.aspx

Before trying to access the date using key, first check if that key even exists using ContainsKey method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4